# Group by query error in multiple joins

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I need to fetch each select item and its count in single query.Here is my query and expecting the output as single array.

```
select ordetable.order_id, count(ordetable.order_id), order_table.name,
       count(order_table.na me), orderitem_table.itemname,
       count(orderitem_table.itemname)
from order_table
left join orderitem_table
    on order_table.order_id = orderitem_table.order_id
group by ordetable.order_id
```

Am getting this error:

> [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Column
>   'orderitem_table.itemname' is invalid in the select list because it is
>   not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: The general GROUP BY rule says: If a GROUP BY clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function!

Comment: You should add `order_table.name`, `orderitem_table.itemname` to `group by`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is evident from the error message, isn't it?

Modify your query like below.

```
select ordetable.order_id, count(ordetable.order_id), order_table.name,
       count(order_table.name), orderitem_table.itemname,
       count(orderitem_table.itemname)
from order_table
left join orderitem_table
    on order_table.order_id = orderitem_table.order_id
group by ordetable.order_id, order_table.name, orderitem_table.itemname
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, can i confirm my issue, i need to specify all items in select list to group by if am using group by clause and if am not using aggregate functions with select items.Please confirm am right.Thanks

Comment: Thank you so much, suppose i have two names in an order, is there any way to fetch as array of two names or something.I need to get all values in my array output, both count and values

Answer (score 2):

If you not like to group order_table.name and orderitem_table.itemname, then you can use 'min' condition.

```
select ordetable.order_id, count(ordetable.order_id), min(order_table.name),
       count(order_table.name), min(orderitem_table.itemname),
       count(orderitem_table.itemname)
from order_table
left join orderitem_table
    on order_table.order_id = orderitem_table.order_id
group by ordetable.order_id
```

Comment: thanks for the help , if i user min with item name will i get all names associated with the query?Is there any way to get particular select item as array eg: name array of particular order?

Comment: Yes, you will get all names . There is no array type in SQL query, you can make this result into an array by programming and you can order the result using 'order by' keyword in SQL.

Answer (score 1):

Your wording and your query are not in sync. Each item and its count (over all the orders) will be

```
select orderitem_table.itemname, orderitem_table.itemnumber, count(*)
from order_table
join orderitem_table
    on order_table.order_id = orderitem_table.order_id
group by orderitem_table.itemname, orderitem_table.itemnumber
```

Comment: i need to fetch all select values as well as the count, does the query fetch names too?

Comment: Not sure i understand it well, which values from what tables and columns?

Comment: suppose, i need to fetch one more value say itemnumber, i can specify the field name after select key word in the query no?count(*) will count all fields i specify in select?

Comment: Yes, you can. Remember non-aggregated columns in SELECT must be mentioned in GROUP BY as well. Count(*) will count number of rows  for  every combination of `itemname` + `itemnumber`  See update.